# Copy all the data from Employee table from database to A to Employee table on Database B

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I want to copy all (*) data in the `Employee` table from database to A to  `Employee` table in database B. Both employee table's structure are the same.

I have 50 plus columns of values in the `Employee` table and I want to copy all the data from A to B.

Please help me with a pseudo query.

PS: my database A & B are on the same server. I don't know if this matters.

Comment: What about the [`INSERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) statement do you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

You can set an INSERT instruction without defining the columns, so all columns are going to be inserted. You just need to couple that INSERT with a SELECT * from the source :

```
INSERT INTO B.dbo.EMPLOYEE 
       SELECT * FROM A.dbo.EMPLOYEE
```

This will only work if both tables have the exact same structure and you want to copy all those columns.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the datatype of each column is same in both the databases and then you can simply use insert into option.

```
INSERT INTO B.database.EMPLOYEE 
    SELECT * FROM A.database.EMPLOYEE
```

If the datatype of any column is different use `cast` to change it.

Answer (score 0):

you don't indicate if your target table is empty or already contains data to which you are adding.

However if it's emtpy and you are simply copying the entire table from database A to database B you do not need the table to be pre-existing,

```
use A
Go

select *
into B.dbo.DestinationTable
from SourceTable
```

If the table exists and contains data, provided the columns are identical and in the same order, you simply say

```
insert into B.dbo.DestinationTable
select * from SourceTable
```

Answer (score 0):

In SSMS if you left-click and drag the "Columns" folder under a table to a query window, it will paste a delimited list of the column names.

[image]

Which makes it very easy to write the property query without `select *`, or INSERT without a column list.  eg

```
insert into OtherDatabase.HumanResources.Employee 
      ( [BusinessEntityID], [NationalIDNumber], [LoginID], [OrganizationNode], [OrganizationLevel], [JobTitle], [BirthDate], [MaritalStatus], [Gender], [HireDate], [SalariedFlag], [VacationHours], [SickLeaveHours], [CurrentFlag], [rowguid], [ModifiedDate] )
select  [BusinessEntityID], [NationalIDNumber], [LoginID], [OrganizationNode], [OrganizationLevel], [JobTitle], [BirthDate], [MaritalStatus], [Gender], [HireDate], [SalariedFlag], [VacationHours], [SickLeaveHours], [CurrentFlag], [rowguid], [ModifiedDate]
from AdventureWorks2017.HumanResources.Employee
```